# Converting multiple images into tensor at once

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have ~10 images. They images are different in size. I am reading them in OpenCV and converting all of them to (54, 54, 3). I know that I can convert each one of them to a tensor. Is there any way of converting them to tensors altogether? Final tensor will have a shape of (10, 54, 54, 3)

I am trying to use the following codes for single image conversion.

```
import cv2, glob
import tensorflow as tf
lst = glob.glob("images/*jpg")

im1 = cv2.imread(lst[1])
im1_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(im1, dtype=tf.int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to do batch processing. I have used [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) API.

```
def parse_image(filepath):
    # Write your own parsing logic in this function
    image = tf.io.read_file(filepath)
    image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image)
    image = tf.io.encode_jpeg(image)
    return image

batch_size = 10
pred_files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(IMAGE_PATH/"*"))
pred_imgs_ds = pred_files_ds.map(lambda x: parse_image(x))
for img_batch in pred_imgs_ds.batch(batch_size):
    print(img_batch.shape)
```